# Updating two values, with a second value having a where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

This may be pointless but I want in ONE query to only the second value when Eligible equals 1, but always update the first value. So if the eligible is already 0 (or something else), don't update eligible. Can I do this in one query?

```
  ---Looping through this
  UPDATE myTable p
   SET p.first= 'C', p.eligible = 0
   WHERE id = l_modifier_row_a.id
```

Desired Results

BEFORE

```
ID First Eligible
1    A     1
2    B     2
```

AFTER

```
ID First Eligible
 1    C     0
 2    C     2
```

Comment: which db you are using ???

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Orcale @scaisEdge

Comment: @Branderson20 . . . Your query would seem to reference *two* tables.

Comment: @Branderson20 , just for me to understand. you want to update the field eligible to 0 onl y in the first row, so once it is updated, in the next ones should remain the old value ? what is tthe order criteria ?  for ID field ??

Comment: I removed it to make it easier @RobertoHernandez

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, you can use `exists`:

```
UPDATE myTable p
   SET p.first = 'C',
       p.eligible = 0
   WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                 FROM l_modifier_row_a l
                 WHERE p.id = l.id AND p.person_id = l.person_id
                );
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set a multiple column values sometime but not in others, in a single statement the columns are ALWAYS the same. However, you can conditionally set the value of a column to the existing value or change that value.

```
  update mytable p
   set first= 'C'
     , eligible = case when p.eligible = 1 
                         then 0
                         else p.eligible
                    end                
   where id = l_modifier_row_a.id ;
```

This might be doable in a single statement without a loop. But you did not post the loop control so I cannot look further.